# Run php scripts from within phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to run external php scripts(located inside the root folder of my web server) from within phpMyAdmin? The reason being I have some chart scripts which I would like to execute from within phpMyAdmin.

Thanks.

Tim

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "within phpMyAdmin"?

Comment: using phpMyAdmin GUI to run the scripts, i.e. probably bookmarking php scripts in a particular box for easy access to other users.

Comment: Why not simply use a good old fashion HTTP request? phpMyAdmin is of course just a PHP website, so you could probably have it include your scripts manually, but I don't think this is as a standard feature.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this is possible. But what you can do is just bookmark those scripts, or save them into a database and click them from there (within phpMyAdmin).